# i am trying to write code to save to excel but it keeps overwriting

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

i am trying to develop a program to save multiple data to excel without overwriting with previous data, need help.
currently this is what i have;

```
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook() # create empty workbook object
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('my_sheet_name') # sheet name can not be longer than 32 characters
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('sheet1')
sheet1.write(0,0, ' Date')
sheet1.write(0,1, 'Name')
sheet1.write(0,2, 'File number')
sheet1.write(0,3, 'Returned/Taken')

for value in range(2):
  i=0
  j=0
  date = input('please enter date')
  sheet1.write(i+1,j,date) # write contents to a cell, marked by row i, column j
  name = input('please enter your name')
  sheet1.write(i+1,j+1,name)
  n_files = input('how many files would you like')
  n_files = int(n_files)
  for v in range(0,n_files):
    f_number = input('please input filenumber')
    i+=1
    sheet1.write(i,j+2,f_number)
    status = input('are you taking the file yes/no')
    sheet1.write(i ,j+3, status)

# no update allowed for content writing?
wb.save('registry3.xls')
```